# Нельзя преобразовать тип real к integer. Как это можно исправить

Tags: pascal

Задача такая:

> для возведения в квадрат числа, оканчивающегося на 5 надо умножить число, полученное из исходного вычеркиванием последней пятерки на следующее по порядку число, затем приписать «25» к получившемуся результату справа. Например, для того, чтобы возвести число 125 в квадрат достаточно 12 умножить на 13 и приписать 25, т.е. приписывая к числу 12*13=156 число 25, получаем результат 15625, т.е. 1252=15625. Напишите программу, возводящую число, оканчивающееся на 5, в квадрат вот что " c := (c * (с + 1), 25)" означает, возведение в квадрат таким способом

```
program sop;

var
  b: word;
  c: real ;

begin
  writeln('Введите число');
  readln(b);
  if (b mod 10 = 5) or (b mod 100 = 5) or (b mod 1000 = 5) or (b mod 10000 = 5) then
  begin
    c := b;
    c := (c div 10);
    c := (c * (с + 1), 25);
    writeln(c)
  end;
  if b = 5 then
  begin
    writeln(sqr(b))
  end

     else
  begin
    writeln('Ошибка. Повторите попытку, число должно оканчиваться на 5')
  end;
end.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

К вещественному типу неприменима операция целочисленного деления

```
c := (c div 10);
```

А вот это вообще непонятно:

```
c := (c * (b + 1), 25);
```

Вот буквальное исполнение заданного алгоритма. Вещественные числа не нужны.

```
var
   b, sq: Cardinal;
begin
  b := 125;

  if b mod 10 = 5 then begin
    b := b div 10;
    sq := b * (b + 1) * 100 + 25;
    Writeln(sq);
  end;
```

P.S.  `if (b mod 10 = 5)` можно здесь и закончить, остальная часть строки лишняя